# Countdown Timer Excel VBA - Code crashed excel

Tags: excel, vba, timer, crash, countdown

Could someone offer an insight into why this crashes my excel, i cant seem to work it out. 
Im trying to learn VBA and need some advice.

```
sub timer()

    dim second

    second = 1.15740740740741e-05 

'this is the amount excel counts as a second

line1:

    application.wait "00:00:01"

    Range("a1").value = Range("a1").value - second

    if not range("D2").value = 0 then

        Goto line1

            else

            Msgbox("Countdown ended")

    End if

end sub
```

Comment: What is **A1**'s initial value??       How are **A1** and **D2** related??

Comment: OMG im such a twit....

Comment: A1 = 00:00:30  , D2 should be A1 ..... i also changed the wait to 
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:01")

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you're not timing space shuttle launches or anything that critical. But if you want to make sure your countdown doesn't take longer than 30 seconds, you can use the Timer function.  Here's an example.

```
Sub NewTimer()

    Dim Start As Single
    Dim Cell As Range
    Dim CountDown As Date

    'Timer is the number of seconds since midnight.
    'Store timer at this point in a variable
    Start = Timer

    'Store A1 in a variable to make it easier to refer
    'to it later. Also, if the cell changes, you only
    'have to change it in one place
    Set Cell = Sheet1.Range("A1")

    'This is the starting value. Timeserial is a good
    'way to get a time
    CountDown = TimeSerial(0, 0, 30)

    'Set our cell to the starting value
    Cell.Value = CountDown

    'Keep executing this loop until A1 hits zero or
    'even falls slightly below zero
    Do While Cell.Value > 0
        'Update the cell. Timer - Start is the number of seconds
        'that have elapsed since we set Start.
        Cell.Value = CountDown - TimeSerial(0, 0, Timer - Start)

        'DoEvents release control ever so briefly to Windows. This
        'allows Windows to do stuff like update the screen. When you
        'have loops like this, your code appears frozen because it's
        'not letting Windows do anything (unless you have this line)
        DoEvents
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you dick, this has really helped me. This seems a much better way of making this Countdown timer.

Answer (score 1):

If it just about count down every second, I guess there is another option to add a Timer functionality to Excel. 
Try searching for Application.OnTime function in Excel that enables us to have Timer in Excel. [Related Article that explains how to add timer in Excel and make a macro run during that scheduled interval.](http://officetricks.com/run-macro-on-schedule-time-adding-timer-to-excel-vba-using-application-ontime/)

Answer (score 0):

This is the best way to do this.

Try to use this code below:

```
Sub Countup() 
Dim CountDown As Date 
CountDown = Now + TimeValue("00:00:01") 
Application.OnTime CountDown, "Realcount" 
End Sub

Sub Realcount() 'Run this to count down your cell value
Dim count As Range 
Set count = [E1] 'Put the range that you want to count down
count.Value = count.Value - TimeSerial(0, 0, 1) 
If count <= 0 Then 
MsgBox "Countdown complete." 
Exit Sub 
End If 
Call Countup 
End Sub
```