# How to have countdown timer in Excel that continues when inputs are made

Tags: excel, vba

The below code was provided by Dick Kusleika as answer in ([Countdown Timer Excel VBA - Code crashed excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22489755/countdown-timer-excel-vba-code-crashed-excel/24257925#24257925)) and was helpful and it works. But is there any way to improve the above Excel VBA code so that the countdown will continue working despite of any input made in cells?

```
Sub NewTimer()

    Dim Start As Single
    Dim Cell As Range
    Dim CountDown As Date

    'Timer is the number of seconds since midnight.
    'Store timer at this point in a variable
    Start = Timer

    'Store A1 in a variable to make it easier to refer
    'to it later. Also, if the cell changes, you only
    'have to change it in one place
    Set Cell = Sheet1.Range("A1")

    'This is the starting value. Timeserial is a good
    'way to get a time
    CountDown = TimeSerial(0, 0, 30)

    'Set our cell to the starting value
    Cell.Value = CountDown

    'Keep executing this loop until A1 hits zero or
    'even falls slightly below zero
    Do While Cell.Value > 0
        'Update the cell. Timer - Start is the number of seconds
        'that have elapsed since we set Start.
        Cell.Value = CountDown - TimeSerial(0, 0, Timer - Start)

        'DoEvents release control ever so briefly to Windows. This
        'allows Windows to do stuff like update the screen. When you
        'have loops like this, your code appears frozen because it's
        'not letting Windows do anything (unless you have this line)
        DoEvents
    Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try a different approach which uses **Application.OnTime**

**EDIT:**

```
Public iCounter As Date 'Time Value
Public Sub CountDownValue()
Dim rCell, sSheet As String
    rCell = "A1" 'target cell holding timer value
    sSheet = "Sheet1" 'target sheet

    If Sheets(sSheet).Range(rCell).Value > 0 Then
        Sheets(sSheet).Range(rCell).Value = TimeSerial(DateTime.Hour(Sheets(sSheet).Range(rCell).Value), DateTime.Minute(Sheets(sSheet).Range(rCell).Value), DateTime.Second(Sheets(sSheet).Range(rCell).Value) - 1)
        Application.OnTime Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1), "CountDownValue"
    End If
End Sub
Public Sub StartCountDown()
    iCounter = TimeSerial(0, 1, 10) 'how many seconds you want to start countdown with

Dim rCell, sSheet As String
    sSheet = "Sheet1" 'target sheet
    rCell = "A1" 'target cell holding timer value

    'start new countdown
    Sheets(sSheet).Range(rCell).Value = iCounter
    Call CountDownValue
End Sub
```

Code will not get interrupted when you enter value into a cell. Nonetheless you will see that if you start to write long formula into a cell, your timer will be put on hold until you release the cell (you press Enter or move to any other cell). If you want more reliable counter I would maybe use different approach.

Comment: Wow..Thanks Robert! your code has been helpful. More help Pls? : when I changed the value in seconds into more than a minute (i mean 5400 secs. for 1.5 hrs) then it doesn't work right anymore- was it because of integer data type issue? what should it be? and when I tried replicating the timer to other sheets (=Sheet1!A1) the timer still work but not in synch anymore. Any help please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have updated my answer. One thing to note, that this way you can only have one timer at a time. If you want to have the ability to cancel Timer, you will have to figure out yourself :) This code will however get you stated (you can optimize code). Please make sure you close thread when done.

Comment: Just what I've been wishing to happen..Wow! Thank you very much. "The best VBA programmers are here in stackoverflow.com...yeah! :) Good day.

Comment: Good to hear that your problem has been solved. Please make sure you mark answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

1. Put your event date @ cell A1.

   - right click > format > show date & time
   - type it in a way that excel read the time and date right.
2. the put this formula at the next cell(or other)

`=(INT(A1-NOW()))&" Day "&(IF(HOUR(A1)<=HOUR(NOW()),(HOUR(A1)-HOUR(NOW())+24),(HOUR(A1)-HOUR(NOW()))))&" Hour "&(IF(MINUTE(A1)<=MINUTE(NOW()),(MINUTE(A1)-MINUTE(NOW())+60),(MINUTE(A1)-MINUTE(NOW()))))&" Minute "&(IF(SECOND(A1)<=SECOND(NOW()),(SECOND(A1)-SECOND(NOW())+60),(SECOND(A1)-SECOND(NOW()))))&" Second to go."`

3. press enter.

   - Done. a timer, without vba.
   - The catch : the timer will only update itself only when there is any changes/entry done on the cell. It will not be 'live' as the vba one. (fine for me.. , may not for others).

Hope that helps. (^_^)\

Ref :

https://stevechasedocs.wordpress.com/2014/11/19/create-a-countdown-timer-with-dates-in-excel/