# Timer on Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

```
Dim StartTime As Date
Public Declare Function SetTimer Lib "user32" ( _
ByVal HWnd As Long, ByVal nIDEvent As Long, _
ByVal uElapse As Long, ByVal lpTimerFunc As Long) As Long

Public Declare Function KillTimer Lib "user32" ( _
ByVal HWnd As Long, ByVal nIDEvent As Long) As Long

Public TimerID As Long, TimerSeconds As Single, tim As Boolean
Dim Counter As Long

Sub StartTimer()
'~~ Set the timer for 1 second
TimerSeconds = 1
TimerID = SetTimer(0&, 0&, TimerSeconds * 1000&, AddressOf TimerProc)
End Sub

'~~> End Timer
Sub EndTimer()
On Error Resume Next
KillTimer 0&, TimerID
End Sub

Sub TimerProc(ByVal HWnd As Long, ByVal uMsg As Long, _
ByVal nIDEvent As Long, ByVal dwTimer As Long)
'~~> Update value in Sheet 1
Sheet1.Range("H6").Value = Time - StartTimer
End Sub
Public Sub sheet()
Sheets("1").Activate
StartTime = Time
Call Module1.StartTimer
End Sub
```

I would like to write a code which show timer how much time user working on the Worksheet.

Example there  is a start button in sheet1 when user click on start button then it will active sheet2 then a timer will run in cell A1. if the timer is 30 min then the workbook save & close.

Comment: There are many ways to do this, depending on what you need it for. Show us your code, or your effort so far, and then we can help.

Comment: Did you get stuck with this, or are you asking for the whole code?

Comment: Actully i wrote some code while trying to test the code, file get hanged & now I am unable to open that file. It's showing file is get locked.

Comment: Look at the `Application.OnTime` method.

Comment: I shared my code please review

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

Create Button and assign to the following macro

```
Option Explicit
Sub NewTimer()
    Dim Start As Single
    Dim Cell As Range
    Dim CountDown As Date

    '// Store timer as variable
    Start = Timer

    '// Format cell A1 to 24Hrs eg: 00:00:00
    With Range("A1")
        .NumberFormat = "HH:MM:SS;@"
    End With
    Set Cell = Sheet1.Range("A1")

    '// This is the starting value. 30 Second
    CountDown = TimeValue("00:00:30")

    '// Set cell to the starting value
    Cell.Value = CountDown

    'Keep looping until A1 hits zero or
    Do While Cell.Value > 0
        'Update the cell. Timer - Starting number is seconds
        Cell.Value = CountDown - TimeSerial(0, 0, Timer - Start)
        DoEvents
    Loop

    ThisWorkbook.Save
    ThisWorkbook.Close
    Application.Quit

End Sub
```

Thanks to [Dick Kusleika](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4280/dick-kusleika) See [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22489755/countdown-timer-excel-vba-code-crashed-excel)